# Merging two Jena models

Tags: rdf, jena

I aim to create two models m1 and m2: m1 reads a message from ActiveMQ and m2 extracts an additional information from DataBase using SPARQL queries. Then I want to emerge the two models into single one.
The syntax of the models is as follow:

```
<http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/records/teste>   <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator>  ?o0.
```

```
?o0  a   <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/person>.
```

How can i merge them it please so that the resulted model will be like that

```
<http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/records/teste>   <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator>  ?o0.
?o0  a   <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/person>.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the edit to [the answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23271163/2528639), I note that models are only sets of triples, and that you can add them together to merge them. In this case, it seems that you have some criteria that you want to join the models by. From the phrasing of yoru question, you have a consistent set of URIs that is used across both models (ie: `?o0` exists in *both* models).

If there is some indeed such a natural criteria to join the two models on then there is nothing that stops you from using a union of the two models in order to answer your queries:

```
final Model amqp = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
// do things to populate this from your AMQP store
final Model dbresult = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
// do things to populate this from your query

final Model union = ModelFactory.createUnion(amqp, dbresult);
```

Additionally, because the RDF Data Model defines a model merely as a set of RDF `Statement`s, you can just add the two models together.

```
final Model amqp = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
final Model dbresult = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

final Model union = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
union.add(amqp);
union.add(dbresult)
```

If the URIs do *not* align, then you will need to manually define some criteria by which to join them. You will either need to write custom code that is sensitive to this criteria and will manually write a new model based on it, or you will need to define some ontological rational for their equivalency and utilize a reasoner.